# How can I use an if/else-statement within predicates?

Tags: java, jpa, criteria, predicate

So I have this piece of code here:

```
final CriteriaBuilder builder = JPA.em().getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<Ticket> criteria = builder.createQuery(Ticket.class);
    Root<Ticket> ticketRoot = criteria.from(Ticket.class);
    Join<Ticket, Order> order = ticketRoot.join("order", JoinType.LEFT);
    Join<Ticket, EventGroup> eventGroups = ticketRoot.join("eventGroup", JoinType.LEFT);
    final List<javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();


if (from != null) {
    predicates.add(
        builder.or(
            builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(order.get("completedOn"), from),
            builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(ticketRoot.get("refundedAt"), from)
        )
    );
}
```

It now looks for tickets with `completedOn` OR `refundedAt` with a date after `from`. I want to change this.

What I want to have now is the following:
If a ticket's `refundedAt` is *not* `null`, get `refundedAt` with date after `from`, else get `completedOn` with date after `from`.

I tried to use `builder.selectCase()`, also in combination with `criteria.multiSelect()`, but that didn't work.

I hope somebody can help me.

**Edit:**
To make the current situation clear, this is the if/else-statement explained:

**IF** `refundedAt` is not null, get the ticket ONLY if `refundedAt` is after `from`.

**ELSE** (`refundedAt` is null) get the ticket ONLY if `completedOn` is after `from`.

Comment: You may be looking for the Java ternary operator - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/ternary-operator.html

Comment: I tried to do the following:

```predicates.add(ticketRoot.get("refundedAt") == null ? builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(order.get("completedOn"), from) : builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(ticketRoot.get("refundedAt"), from)
);```

It doesn't throw an error, but the created query is not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `and` and `or` :

```java
predicates.add(
    builder.or(
        builder.and(    
            builder.isNotNull(ticketRoot.get("refundedAt")),        
            builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(ticketRoot.get("refundedAt"), from)
        ),
        builder.and(            
            builder.isNull(ticketRoot.get("refundedAt")), 
            builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(order.get("completedOn"), from)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't work. The required type for ```predicates``` is ```Predicate```. The ```selectCase()``` returns an ```Expression<java.lang.Object>```.

Comment: @TBatist Since `greaterThanOrEqualTo` returns a Predicate, the return value of otherwise could be  `Expression<Boolean>` which is a predicate. Not sure, but it might work if you add casting `(Predicate) builder.selectCase()`

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought as well, but it gives an error; Inconvertible types. So I can't cast it.

Comment: @TBatist I have updated the answer -> you need to use `as` to convert `Expression<Object>` to `Expression<Boolean>`, then you could cast to predicate

Comment: Unfortunately, this throws a ```ClassCastException```. So it did compile, but it throw it runtime. (SearchedCaseExpression cannot be cast to Predicate)

Comment: @TBatist I am updating the answer using just `and` `or`. Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is still not completely right. With this solution I'm back at the beginning, because it now always searches for tickets with ```completedOn``` after from. I only want this when a ticket is not refunded, so when ```refundedAt``` is not null.

Comment: @TBatist So that means `notnull(refundedAt) AND ((refundedAt after from) OR (completedOn after from))` ? Is this the requirement?

Comment: No, not exactly. It is more like an if/else
**if:** Ticket is refunded (`refundedAt != null`) -> only look at `refundedAt` after from
**else:** Ticket is not refunded (`refundedAt == null`) -> only look at `completedAt` after from.

I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: @TBatist got it now. May be you could add this statement to the question

Comment: @TBatist So how about `(notnull(refundedAt) AND (refundedAt after from)) OR (isnull(refundedAt) AND completedOn after from))`